# Скопировать все файлы из одного Amazon S3 хранилища в другое

Tags: amazon, amazon-s3

Необходимо развернуть клон уже имеющегося S3-хранилища.

В оригинальном хранилище 30 тысяч файлов. Как можно скопировать все файлы с одного хранилища в другое?

Comment: День добрый. Пробовал предложенный вариант? (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью [s3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd):

```
s3cmd sync s3://from/this/bucket/ s3://to/this/bucket/
```